# Accessing Google Cloud Storage from local Jupyter and Notebooks in Google AI Platform / Vertex AI

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

Problem statement: have Google Cloud Storage with some Buckets. Need to import data from such buckets into:

- a local Jupyter instance running on my local computer
- a Google Colab notebook
- a JupyterLab notebook in Vertex AI (and/or AI Platform)

Any reference code to be able these cases would be appreciated.
Kind Regards

Comment: If you create a new Notebook, you can use the tutorials there. A quick Google search can give you the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**local Jupyter instance**: First authenticate your local env using [gcloud auth login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login) then use [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) to copy the content to local env.

```
# Authenticate with your account
!gcloud auth login --no-browser

# Copy from your bucket to local path (note -r is for recursive call)
!gsutil cp -r gs://BUCKET/DIR_PATH ./TARGET_DIR
```

**Colab**: First authenticate your Colab session to get access to the cloud APIs.Then you can use `gsutil` to copy the content to the local env.

```
# Authenticate with your account
from google.colab import auth as google_auth
google_auth.authenticate_user()

# Copy from your bucket to local path (note -r is for recursive call)
!gsutil cp -r gs://BUCKET/DIR_PATH ./TARGET_DIR
```

**JupyterLab notebook in Vertex AI**: Your env is already authenticated. Use gsutil to copy the content to local env.

```
# Copy from your bucket to local path (note -r is for recursive call)
!gsutil cp -r gs://BUCKET/DIR_PATH ./TARGET_DIR
```

You can also directly access the files in your Google Cloud Storage via Python using the [Cloud Storage client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python). You will need to authenticate your environment first as mentioned above.

```
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import storage

# Instantiates a client
storage_client = storage.Client()

# The name for the new bucket
bucket_name = "my-new-bucket"

# Creates the new bucket
bucket = storage_client.create_bucket(bucket_name)

print(f"Bucket {bucket.name} created.")
```